# Is there a list of open mail relays I can use for a pentest?

Tags: smtp

I'm currently pentesing a client (with permission of course) and we are testing their email filtering capabilities. We want to check whether they reject mail coming from open mail relays, but I seem unable to find any. Is there a list somewhere that we can use? The less reputable the better.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is essentially asking for a list of vulnerable system which can be misused to attack other systems, i.e. send phishing, spam, bomb threads etc. Disclosing such a list here would be irresponsible and also hopefully quickly out of date.

Comment: Questions of the type, "where can I find X?" are generally off-topic here.

Comment: The better option is to set up your open relay instead of abusing someone else's misconfigured system.

Comment: @schroeder: Setting up an own open relay for this purpose is impractical: the mail server doesn't test for open relay by trying to relay thought the originating server, but by querying a DNSBL. An own open relay should be actually abused before getting on such list, making you part of the problem! That's why the misconfiguration should be revealed by directly examining the server configuration. No need to pentest for obvious errors.

Comment: @EsaJokinen I would also submit my personal open relay to these reputation sites.

Comment: While that would give the same results, this is something you can test easily by reading the server logs. There will be natural spam from open relays, either rejected or not. I think we just have different perspectives (black-box / white-box).

Comment: @EsaJokinen but that test is an inference, not a positive test. Setting up a known mail relay that is not going to be abused is a positive test.

Answer (score 1):

There are *Domain Name System-based Blackhole List* (DNSBL) like [SORBS](http://www.sorbs.net/faq/), but they all work the other way around, allowing to test reputation for known IP address. There's a good reason for that.

While you may have permission to test your client's systems, but you don't have permission to use 3rd party servers for your penetration testing! The open relay servers are typically in this condition by accident.

You are confusing two different things: technological term [open relay](https://www.spamhaus.org/news/article/706/the-return-of-the-open-relays) and [Mailgun’s service](https://www.mailgun.com/smtp/free-smtp-service/free-open-smtp-relay), which isn't really open as it needs registration. The latter is not illegal, but for the same reason it's not any good for your penetration testing, as it's not necessarily blocked by a DNSBL even if your client has one or more configured.

Instead, you should be testing if your client's servers works as an open relay or a partly open relay due to misconfiguration. Recommendations regarding inbound spam filtering can be given without testing, based on the mail server configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you clarify something though? When you say "You don't have permission to use 3rd party servers for your penetration testing!" what exactly do you mean? Aren't open relay servers specifically for forwarding mail? And we're not trying to pentest the servers themselves. One of the services I found was this: https://www.mailgun.com/smtp/free-smtp-service/free-open-smtp-relay, and as we're not spamming or phishing using the service I don't think it's against their ToS

Comment: I tried to clarify this in my edit.

Comment: Yea that makes a lot of sense actually I was pretty confused as to why mailgun was calling itself an open relay but required registration. Is that a mislabeling on their part?